# Django strategy for automatically suggesting matching content

Tags: django

I'm looking at porting a custom-written PHP CMS into Django. One of the features the CMS currently has is an image upload function. I write an article, tag it with information, then choose a photo for it. If the system has any photos which have been added to articles with tags in common with the new one, it will suggest the photo for that article too. If there are no matches then a new image can be added.

In case this doesn't make sense, let's say I tag an article as `Bruce Springsteen`, `The Beatles` and `Led Zeppelin`. Next time I add an article with the tag `The Beatles`, it should suggest I use the image added for the first article.

What would be the best Django-applicable way to implement this? I've looked at the Photologue app and have integrated it, and I know it has tagging support (the problem here is that I'm using `django-taggit`, whereas Photologue supports `django-tagging`). One approach could be simply building it myself -- when a user uploads an article, I run a hook after they save it to associate the tags with the image. I'm just not sure how to then autosuggest an image in the admin tools based on that info.

Any ideas/approaches greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you're ok on the model end -- you'll be able to select a queryset of the appropriate images.  You just need to know how to build an admin tools widget to show them?  By admin tools do you mean [django-admin-tools](https://bitbucket.org/izi/django-admin-tools/wiki/Home)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly something you're going to have to build yourself. Django has a moderate number of libraries out there (that you've clearly already found). Unlike other solutions, it doesn't have a lot of things that get you 100% to your desired solution (whereas  something like Drupal might get you 100% of the way there).

What you will probably need to do (at a high level) is something like this:

- Create an AJAX view that takes the current tags as an argument and does a query on the existing posts to see what tags match and returns images from those posts.
- Use jQuery/javascript on your view to call your AJAX view on the page as tags are added
- Use jQuery to update a `<div>` on your page and show all the images that your view returned

Here is a [similar example](http://mitchfournier.com/2011/06/06/getting-started-with-ajax-in-django-a-simple-jquery-approach/) that might help get you started.

You might look into [django-ajax](https://github.com/joestump/django-ajax) as a helper library for your requests, but it definitely isn't necessary.

Comment: Cheers for this. I want to do all of this within Django's admin area, so not sure how flexible it can be in terms of dynamically suggesting things which can then be selected. I might rethink the model, but these tips are useful - thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the Django admin will present a pretty constant challenge to just about anything you want to do to it. You might be able to override the template and slip in you template variables with a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) although I've never tried to do that within the admin, so I don't know if it will work. Might be worth considering designing a front-end page to do this task.

Answer (score 1):

The hook between the your image module and any other django module can be implemented using django's [contenttypes framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) which also provides some useful instance methods for returning related/hooked objects.